# Why doesn't gsettings recognise these keys/values?

Tags: gnome

On previous versions of Ubuntu, I was able to execute these gsettings commands from a script I use to set up a new laptop:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface.show-battery-percentage true
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences.default-folder-viewer 'list-view'
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.list-view.default-zoom-level 'small'
```

But as of 20.04, I can't:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.list-view.default-zoom-level 'small'
Usage:
  gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] set SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE

Set the value of KEY to VALUE

Arguments:
  SCHEMADIR A directory to search for additional schemas
  SCHEMA    The name of the schema
  PATH      The path, for relocatable schemas
  KEY       The key within the schema
  VALUE     The value to set
```

If I do this on the UI though, such as with gnome-tweaks, and if I run `dconf watch /` while doing it, everything looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the schema file `/usr/share/glib2.0/schemas/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml`

```
  <schema path="/org/gnome/nautilus/list-view/" id="org.gnome.nautilus.list-view" gettext-domain="nautilus">
    <key name="default-zoom-level" enum="org.gnome.nautilus.ListZoomLevel">
      <default>'standard'</default>
      <summary>Default list view zoom level</summary>
    </key>
```

`SCHEMA = org.gnome.nautilus.list-view`
`KEY = default-zoom-level`

`gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] set SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE`

To simplify Above

`gsettings set SCHEMA KEY VALUE`
`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-zoom-level $VALUE`

so your gsettings command should be, for example

```
gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-zoom-level
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-zoom-level '$value'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I guess this was never actually working previously.